# Generate zero-inflated random vector

Tags: r, probability, distributions, zero-inflation

I want to randomly generate a vector of size `n`  - that represents hypothetical revenues per users in a webshop.

Typically I would imagine this distribution to have:

- a disproportionate amount of 0 (users that do not buy, let's say around 95%)
- a lower bound at 0 (users can't buy for less than zero dollars)
- unbounded above (users are unlimited in their potential expenditure)

The distribution will hence be right-skewed.

In R, I tried with:

```
pois_data <-rpois(100,lambda=0.01) 
lambda_est <- mean(pois_data)
p0_tilde <- exp(-lambda_est)
# number of observtions 'expected' to be zero
n*p0_tilde
97.0445533548508
```

In this Poisson I have a 97% of 0s, but instead of the observation valued 1, I want continuous values that might reflect an hypothetical distrubution of revenues (I read that typically would be drawn from a lognormal).

How can I do that in R?

Comment: Zero-inflated data is the result of a two-step process: The first step decides if the data is zero or not (buy or don't buy), the second step decides the value for non-zero data (how much did the users pay). Your simulation therefore should include two calls to RNG functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
isZero = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 0.97)
data = ifelse(isZero==1, 0, rlnorm(sum(isZero==0), meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1))
```

Should do the job. As mentioned it is a two-step aproach. Modify the parameters of the log-normal distribution at will.